# API Connect shows "Cannot GET /apim/" error when updating schema

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have API Connect installed with mongodb connector over a remote server.

When I access the IBM API Connect through browser, all is fine, but when I go to DataSources where my DB is, and try to hit Update Schema button as shown in the image, an error occurs showing this:

Cannot GET /apim/dataSources/partials/dataSourceMigrate.html

P.S. I gave full permission for my project directory (/var/www/) with full ownership for www-data group and still the same.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your terminal?

Comment: Yes.. I already mentioned:Cannot GET /apim/dataSources/partials/dataSourceMigrate.html

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY AND AFTER 2 MONTHS OF WAITING, I've got an answer from IBM Bluemix Support and sorry to bring the bad news, which is the following:

Hi Ghassan,

Thanks for sending the additional files. I checked with our development team and they found a bug in the code.
The fix will be available in a future release of the apic command line, but I don't have a date for it yet.
I will further discuss the plans to release this fix and will update you as soon as possible.

IBM Bluemix Developer Support and Enablement Team

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been provided for this issue in iFix versions of 5.0.3.0, 5.0.4.0 as well as newer versions of API Connect. If you are still experiencing this issue, please update to a later version that includes the fix.