# APIC Cannot GET /apim while updating schema

Tags: mongodb, azure, ubuntu, apiconnect

am new to stackoverflow, and I thought of sharing this regarding an IBM product called APIC.

I did the whole deployment correctly as recommended by IBM on an Ubuntu Environment with mongoDB and MySQL using an AZURE Virtual Machine as Server. Whenever I try to update the schema of the database with the new models, I get an error saying:

Cannot GET /apim/dataSources/partials/dataSourceMigrate.html

Please help or ask me anything in case you need more info, and tell me if it's an error from Azure or IBM or me.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API Connect shows "Cannot GET /apim/" error when updating schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244336/api-connect-shows-cannot-get-apim-error-when-updating-schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exactly happened to me once, and I contacted IBM for several weeks of give and take, to find out it's a bug on their side, not on the cloud side or your side :)

Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016171/4694311

In this case, go back to using strongloop until they get it fixed.

Note that his is a bug on the operating system itself, it works on iOS but that would be useless on cloud.